# Primitives does not show on screen

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to render terrain, everything compiles fine, but I can't see anything on screen. ( I'm moving camera around in case it was on the other side)

Can't figure out whats wrong.

```
public class Terrain
    {
        public VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
        public IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
        public VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices;
        public int[] indices;
        //int gridSize;

        Camera camera;
        ContentManager Content;
        GraphicsDevice device;

        Texture2D heightmap;
        public Texture2D grass;

        Effect effect;


        public Terrain(ContentManager Content, GraphicsDevice device, Camera camera)
        {
            this.Content = Content;
            this.device = device;
            this.camera = camera;

            heightmap = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Gfx//heightmap");
            grass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Gfx//grass");

            effect = Content.Load<Effect>("Effects//terrain");

            CreateVertices();
            CreateIndices();
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Texture1"];
            effect.Parameters["xWorldViewProjection"].SetValue(camera.worldMatrix * camera.viewMatrix * camera.projMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xTexture"].SetValue(grass);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3);
            }
        }

        private void CreateVertices()
        {
            vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[heightmap.Width * heightmap.Height];
            for (int x = 0; x < heightmap.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < heightmap.Height; y++)
                {
                    vertices[y * heightmap.Width + x].Position = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
                    vertices[y * heightmap.Width + x].Normal = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                    vertices[y * heightmap.Width + x].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(y, x);
                }
            }
            //device.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
        }

        private void CreateIndices()
        {
            indices = new int[(heightmap.Width - 1) * (heightmap.Height - 1) * 6];
            int counter = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < heightmap.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < heightmap.Height - 1; y++)
                {
                    int lowerLeft = x + y * heightmap.Width;
                    int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * heightmap.Width;
                    int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * heightmap.Width;
                    int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * heightmap.Width;

                    indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;

                    indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                    indices[counter++] = topRight;
                    indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start with a working example and expand on that. Run frequently to know if any changes affect your output. And run [the debugger](http://byte56devtips.tumblr.com/post/20149822772/debuggers-breaking-bad-code) to find out what values are set to, and see where things are going wrong.

Comment: Try reversing the winding of your terrain vertices. Try turning off culling. Try setting the r, g, b, and a values of the terrain pixel shader to 1 (you should see black terrain). Inspect your final terrain index and vertex buffers to see if they look like what you would expect. Compile and run between any and all changes like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do you have lighting enabled ? If so, does the terrain have correct normals otherwise it might result in an opaque black as the color
- What was the last thing you changed, change it back see if it works, if so figure out whats wrong with the snippet / algorithm
- Are you setting the texture correctly or are you using opaque black as some sort of default color

Otherwise you might want to check errors after rendering with your index buffer, it might well be that the indices are incorrect.